# Comparison between two strings is not working

Tags: string, powershell, if-statement

I've got a problem with a comparison between two Versions.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $soft.DisplayVersion -lt "124.0"
False
```

I expect it to return True because the value of $soft.DisplayVersion is :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $soft.DisplayVersion
95.0
```

Object Type :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $soft.DisplayVersion.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                            
True     True     String
```

I also tried this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $soft.DisplayVersion -lt 124.0
False
```

I don't know if it helps but $soft.DisplayVersion comes from this:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object DisplayName -match "Mozilla Firefox"
```

Let me know if you need extra information to understand my problem.

Comment: You are comparing a string with a string which is not the same as comparing to numbers.  Try : [decimal]$soft.DisplayVersion -lt 124.0

Comment: Or `124.0 -ge $soft.DisplayVersion`

Comment: Why this would work : ```124.0 -ge $soft.DisplayVersion``` and not this : ```$soft.DisplayVersion -lt 124.0```

Comment: The 2nd thing gets converted to a number.

Comment: The second parameter ($soft.DisplayVersion) get convert to number ? And you can't compare with -lt String and Number ?

Comment: @S.Me The argument on the right will be converted to the type of the argument on the left, so `<Number> + <String>` evaluates as `<Number> + <String converted to Number>`

Comment: 124.0 is a number so the second item $soft.DisplayVersion will get automatically converted to the same type as first item.

Comment: This would make an exception though `1.0 -lt '1.0.1'`

Comment: @jdweng: No: Since the LHS is a string and the RHS a number, the number is converted to a string; try `'2' -gt 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry key of origin and the comparison operand imply that you're dealing with *version numbers*.

**To meaningfully compare version numbers based on their *string representations*, cast them to `[version]`**:

```bash
[version] $soft.DisplayVersion -lt [version] '124.0'
```

Note:

- For brevity, you could omit the RHS `[version]` cast, because the LHS cast would implicitly coerce the RHS to `[version]` too. However, using it on both sides can help conceptual clarity.
- For a [`[version]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) cast to succeed, the input string must have *at least 2* components (e.g. `[version] '124.0'` and *at most 4* (e.g, `[version] '124.0.1.2'`), and each component must be a positive decimal integer (including `0`).
- `[version]` is *not* capable of parsing [*semantic* version numbers](https://semver.org/), however, which are limited to *3 components* and may contain non-numeric suffixes (e.g., `7.5.0-preview.2`).

  - Use **[`[semver]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion) to parse *semantic versions***; however, that type is available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only.
  - Unlike with `[version]`, a *single* component is sufficient in the input string of a `[semver]` cast; e.g.,
    `[semver] '124'` works to create version `124.0.0`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$soft.DisplayVersion -lt "124.0"` and `$soft.DisplayVersion -lt 124.0` are *equivalent*, and neither works as intended:

  - Because the *LHS* operand is a *string*, `-lt` coerces the RHS operand to a string too, and then performs *lexical* comparison, which is not what you want: `'95.0' -lt '124.0'` `'95.0' -lt 124.0` are both *false*, because the *character* `'9'` is *greater than* the character `'1'`.
- `[decimal]$soft.DisplayVersion -lt 124.0` (from [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78231854/45375)) works only for version-number strings *up to two components*; e.g. `[decimal] '95.0.1'` would break.

Comment: Just note the casting will fail if the string does not use semantic versioning formatting("Major.Minor.Build.Revision", all of them only numbers).

Comment: The right side version cast will be automatic, but it certainly helps readability.

Comment: Thanks, @sirtao; actually what you're describing is the limited format supported by `[version]`, which differs from _semantic_ version numbers. Please see my update for clarification.

Comment: `[semver]'7.5.0-preview.2'` I didn't know that one.

Comment: I didn't know about '[semver]`, awesome, thank you

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to explain all of this !! This is exactly what I needed so now i've got this : ``` [version]$soft.DisplayVersion -lt [version]"124.0.1"```

Answer (score 1):

I will used this syntax :

```
[version]$soft.DisplayVersion -lt [version]"124.0.1"


PS C:\Windows\system32> [version]$soft.DisplayVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
124    0      1      -1      



PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Thanks @lit and @mklement0 this is perfect :)